# Loading a JPEG image from an Access Database into a TDBImage component

Tags: delphi, ado, pascal

I'm trying to link a database image to a TDBImage component in delphi 10 but it keeps giving me the error that my specified field cannot be found even though there aren't any syntax errors.
This is the code I'm using.

```
function TForm1.JPEGStartBlob(fPic: TBlobField): integer;
var
  bS: TADOBlobStream;
  buffer: Word;
  hx: string;
begin
  Result := -1;

  bS := TADOBlobStream.Create(fPic, bmRead);

  try
    while (Result = -1) and (bS.Position + 1 < bS.Size) do
    begin
      bS.ReadBuffer(buffer, 1);
      hx := IntToHex(buffer, 2);
      if hx = 'FF' then
      begin
        bS.ReadBuffer(buffer, 1);
        hx := IntToHex(buffer, 2);
        if hx = 'D8' then
          Result := bS.Position - 2
        else if hx = 'FF' then
          bS.Position := bS.Position - 1;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    bS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowImage(Sender: TObject);
var
 bsImage : TADOBlobStream;
 jImage : TJPEGImage;
begin
  bsImage := TADOBlobStream.Create(adoLodgeI.FieldByName('Image') // this is the field that can't be 
                                                                 // found
      AS TBlobField, bmRead);

  try
    bsImage.Seek(JPEGStartBlob(adoLodgeI.FieldByName('Image') AS TBlobField),
      soFromBeginning);
    jImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      jImage.LoadFromStream(bsImage);
      dbiLodge1.Picture.Graphic := jImage;
    finally
      jImage.Free;
    end;
  finally
    bsImage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If anyone can help it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that the dataset your adoLodgeI is accessing actually contains a field named 'Image'?  If not, you are bound to get the error.

Comment: the dataset does contain the 'Image' field.

Comment: So if you add `Assert(adoLodgeI.Active); Assert(adoLodgeI.FieldByName('Image') <> Nil);` at the start of your `ShowImage`, neither of those raises an exception?

Comment: Where is the code that opens the DataSet before ShowImage() is called?

Comment: Try `adoLodgeI.FindField('Image');` if it returns nil, the field is not there. Something is probably wrong in how `adoLodgeI` is being connected to the DB, ie, it is not connected.

Comment: @BrynLewis:  That was the point of my Asserts.  The simplest explanation is that the OP hasn't defined a persistent TField for the image and has simply omitted to call Open on adoLodgeI.

Comment: Which version you're using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`TWICImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Graphics.TWICImage) and then you can just assign it a the [`TDBImage.Picture`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture) directly

```
Var
  AStream: TMemoryStream;
  APic: TWICImage;
begin
  AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // Here "Data" is a BlobField
    AStream:= TMemoryStream(TPics.CreateBlobStream(TPics.FieldByName('Data'), bmRead));
    AStream.Position:= 0;
    APic := TWICImage.Create;
    try
      APic.LoadFromStream(AStream);
      DBImage1.Picture.Assign(APic);
    finally
      APic.Free;
    end;
  finally
    AStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Works with `*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png;*.bmp;*.ico` images and you don't need to worry about if the image is a `TJPEGImage` or not.